# Template argument default value for built-in types

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this function:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(const T& var = T()) {
  return var;
}
```

This call is obviously safe:

```
foo<std::string>()
```

Are those?

```
foo<int>()
foo<bool>()
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are perfectly fine. An expression of the form `T()` creates an object of type `T` and value-initializes it. Value-initializing an `int` or `bool` is the same as zero-initializing them. That is, the parameter `var` will have value 0.

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type [...] creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type `T`

Value-initialization is defined as:

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type [...]
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type [...]
> - if `T` is an array type, [...]
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Zero-initialization is defined as:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value `0` (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to `T`;
> - [...]

The temporary object created by `T()` is then bound to the `const` reference, which extends its lifetime.

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...] The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.